# Remove commas from a list and convert Hexadecimal into Decimal value

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion, data-conversion

I am trying to extract variable length Hexadecimal value from BLF log file starting indexed at position [7]. I can successfully extract the variable length 'hexadecimal' values in a list.
The problem is removing the commas between the hexadecimal values from each extracted list.

Below is the BLF file from which I am extracting the variable length hexadecimal values:

```
['Timestamp:', '1546626931.138813', 'ID:', '0764', 'S', 'DLC:', '8', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', 'Channel:', '0']
['Timestamp:', '1546626931.138954', 'ID:', '0365', 'S', 'DLC:', '8', '00', '00', '00', '80', 'db', '80', 'a2', '7f', 'Channel:', '1']
['Timestamp:', '1546626931.139053', 'ID:', '0765', 'S', 'DLC:', '6', 'ae', '05', '00', '00', '05', '00', 'Channel:', '1']
['Timestamp:', '1546626931.139697', 'ID:', '022a', 'S', 'DLC:', '4', '40', 'c0', '50', '6c', 'Channel:', '1']
.
.
.
.
```

The output I am getting in a file is as follows:

```
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00']
['00', '00', '00', '80', 'db', '80', 'a2', '7f']
['ae', '05', '00', '00', '05', '00']
['40', 'c0', '50', '6c']
```

But I what I want is as below is to first remove the commas from the original list amd then convert the hexadecimal values shown below into decimal:

```
['0000000000000000']
['00000080db80a27f']
['ae0500000500']
['40c0506c']
```

My code is below:

```
import can
import csv
import datetime
# import timestamp as timestamp

filename = open('C:\\Users\\xyz\\Downloads\\BLF File\\hex_Decimal.csv', "w")
log1 = can.BLFReader('C:\\Users\\xyz\\Downloads\\BLF File\\test.blf')


#Extracting Hexadecimal and convert into decimal
for time in log1:
    time = str(time).split()
    data=str(time[7:(7 + int(time[6]))])
    "".join(data)
    print(data)
```

I am unable to remove the commas from the list and convert the list of hexadecimal number into decimal values inside the list. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you search in your browser for "string concatenation" and "convert hex to decimal", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the type of the `time` messages extracted from the BLF file is just a list of strings, you are done:

```
...
#Extracting Hexadecimal and convert into decimal
for time in log1:
    data = int(''.join(time[7:7+int(time[6])]), 16)
    print([data])
```

You should get:

```
[0]
[553438454399]
[191336498070784]
[1086345324]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `int(<string with hex number>, 16)` to convert do decimal value:

```
data = [
['00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00'],
['00', '00', '00', '80', 'db', '80', 'a2', '7f'],
['ae', '05', '00', '00', '05', '00'],
['40', 'c0', '50', '6c'],
]

for row in data:
    s = ''.join(row)
    print('{: <{}}: {}'.format(s, 16, int(s, 16)))
```

Prints:

```
0000000000000000: 0
00000080db80a27f: 553438454399
ae0500000500    : 191336498070784
40c0506c        : 1086345324
```

Comment: Can you tell me a command to just print the list of decimal values as final output. 
For Example :

 ```
[0]
[553438454399],
[191336498070784],
[1086345324]

```

Comment: @shrads Then just print `int(s, 16)` and nothing else.